# jstree select element which contains exact string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtree

I must check some nodes of my jstree (checkbox plugin) on page load

```
$j("#tree_data").jstree("check_node",'a:contains('+tool_name+')');
```

but if `tool_name = "aa"` all nodes `abaa, aaa, blaah` will be checked. I need to check only the node that contains exactly "aa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved

```
$j("#tree_data").jstree("check_node",$j("a:contains("+tool_name+")").filter(function() {
        return $j(this).parent().contents().last().text().trim() == tool_name;}));
```